# Circles borders are uneven in React HighCharts

Tags: javascript, reactjs, optimization, highcharts

I'm drawing circles based on data from the backend. And if circles from 1 to 50 are all good:
[image: 0-50 circles]

and if there are 51 or more of them - roughness and animation problems appear (they do not become pale)
[image: 51+ circles]

Here is my HighCharts series config:

```
{
      data: [[el.offset.x, el.offset.y]],
      animation: false,
      color: COMPONENT_TYPE_COLOR_CODE_MAP[el.type],
      customType: el.type,
      customDescription: el.description,
      customName: el.reverseId,
      customOwnerName: el.ownerName,
      customOwnerAvatar: el.ownerAvatar,
      marker: {
        radius: COMPONENT_TYPE_SIZE_CODE_MAP[el.type],
        symbol: 'circle',
      },
      point: {
        events: {
          click: () => onSelectComponentRow(el.reverseId),
        },
      },
      points: [],
    }
```

How can I disable this optimisation?

Comment: Hi @ivan239, I've tried to reproduce the issue, but I don't see any difference between a chart with 40 and 60 scatter points. Could you adapt this live example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/15xny87r/ to show the problem?